# State this proposition for an $\mathcal{L}$-embedding using this convention

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I have started learning logic, and I have been finding it difficult because there seems to by a relatively large disparity between different types of notation in this field of maths compared to other fields  of maths. So far I have come across two different conventions for valuations of variables. I have been reading this text and have so far well-understood it [https://www3.nd.edu/~cmnd/programs/cmnd2016/undergrad/Conant_MTnotes.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ecmnd/programs/cmnd2016/undergrad/Conant_MTnotes.pdf). In this text, the way they assign values to variables, is to treat each variable as an identity function, and then the values we want to assign to those variables are just plugged into that function. The second convention I have seen for valuations is set up like this:

$W^\mathcal{M}=\{w|w\text{ is a function }w:\mathbb{N}\to M\}$. We use $w\in W^\mathcal{M}$ to get such a mapping by declaring that $v_k$ is mapped to $w(k)$.

Let $w\in W^\mathcal{M}$, and let $p\in M$. Then $w(p/i)\in W^\mathcal{M}$ is defined by
$$
w(p/i)(j)=
\begin{cases}
w(j)&\text{if }j\neq i\\
p&\text{if }j=i.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $w(p/i)$ is a valuation that assigns $p$ to $v_i$ irrespective of what $w$ did, but leaves all other values of $w$ unaltered; it thus differs from $w$ only at the "$i$th place".

We have a proposition about embeddings written using the first convention:

For an $\mathcal{L}$-embedding $\pi$ between structures $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, we have that for a variable $v_i$
$$
\pi(v_i^\mathcal{M}(a))=v_i^\mathcal{N}(\pi(a)).
$$

How would I write this proposition using the second convention for valuations?

Comment: The definition of embedding has nothing to do with valuations!

Comment: So in the first definition when they use the vector $a$, in defining how embeddings work for functions, is that not using a valuation? Sorry very new to logic.

Comment: Yes. They are just to show how the elements of $M$ is related to $N$ by the function.

Comment: So would the way to define it for functions to say that $\sigma$ is such that
$$
\sigma(w_\mathcal{M}^*(f(v_i)))=w_\mathcal{N}(\sigma(w_\mathcal{M}^*(f(v_i)))/i)(i),
$$
where $w_\mathcal{N}^*(v_i)=w_\mathcal{N}(i)$ for all $i$?

Comment: @WillHarris What M. Logic is trying to tell you is that the definition of embedding you have quoted in your question makes sense completely independently of knowing what a term is or how to evaluate terms. Fix whatever convention you want for the semantics of terms - the definition of embedding does not need to change.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a bit of sense. I think my question should actually be then how would I express the notion that embeddings preserve valuations of terms in this new notation? For example, with the old notation, we had a Lemma that said that if $\sigma$ is an embedding, then for a variable $t$, we can say that $\sigma(t^\mathcal{M}(a))=t^\mathcal{N}(\sigma(a))$. Sorry for these basic questions.

Comment: @WillHarris No worries! I'm not sure I agree that logic suffers from an unusual diversity of notation relative to other areas of math - but there certainly is a lot of notation to get comfortable with! Can you please edit your question to clarify the question you meant to ask? Thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have edited the question to what I should have asked instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sum up some of the ideas expressed in the comments. We are considering two different things here – *embeddings* and *valuations* – which are fundamentally very different ideas. Let's try to understand what they are and how they differ; fix a first-order language $\mathcal{L}$.

A *valuation* is a kind of map that involves only a *single*, *fixed* $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$; at its most basic level, a valuation on $\mathcal{M}$ is just an assignment of variables in $\mathcal{M}$. In other words, the data of a valuation $w$ is precisely a choice of some element $m_k\in M$ for every variable $v_k$ of the language. The utility of valuations is that they allow us to reason about the *internal logical structure* of $\mathcal{M}$, in the following sense. A first-order formula $\phi$ will generally involve a number of "free variables". For example, the formula $\phi\equiv \exists v_2(v_1\neq v_2)$ has a single free variable – namely, $v_1$ – and can therefore be thought of as expressing a property of the variable $v_1$. (What property is this choice of $\phi$ expressing?) On its own, $\phi$ is not very useful; indeed, if we are considering the logical properties of the structure $\mathcal{M}$, we want to know how the *elements* of $\mathcal{M}$ behave, and $\phi$ as written does not involve any elements of $\mathcal{M}$ – it has variables instead. The way to fix this is by considering suitable valuations; if we want to know whether the sentence $\exists v_2(m\neq v_2)$ holds for some $m\in M$, the right approach is to consider those valuations $w:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{M}$ such that $w(1)=m$, since those valuations are precisely the ones that encode the idea of "substituting $m$ in for the free variables $v_1$". The whole purpose of the machinery and details that you have cited in your post is thus to make precise what it means for a formula to hold when we substitute elements of $\mathcal{M}$ in for its free variables. Once these technical details are dispatched with, we have a framework for turning abstract $\mathcal{L}$-formulas into a tool for thinking about the internal structure of $\mathcal{M}$, and in particular for thinking about how the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ interact with each other.

An *embedding* is a completely different beast. While valuations are maps involving only a single $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$, embeddings are maps involving a *pair* of $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$. If valuations are a tool for understanding the *internal* structure of a *single* $\mathcal{L}$-structure (ie, understanding how its elements interact with each other), then embeddings are a tool for understanding the *external* structure of *multiple* $\mathcal{L}$-structures – namely, understanding the ways that the *$\mathcal{L}$-structures themselves* can interact with each other. Of course, we're not just interested in any old functions between $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$; since we are thinking of $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ as $\mathcal{L}$-structures, we also want embeddings to play nicely with the ambient $\mathcal{L}$-structure (the jargon is that we want an embedding to be a "structure-preserving map" $\sigma:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$), and this motivates the definition of an embedding that you have described in your post. An embedding $\sigma:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ lets us identify $\mathcal{M}$ with an $\mathcal{L}$-substructure of $\mathcal{N}$ (which one?), and allows us to ask what properties are preserved or negated when moving from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{N}$. These kinds of questions are "external" in the sense that they can involve multiple $\mathcal{L}$-structures at a time.

To sum things up, when we are working with valuations, the ambient "universe" that we are working in is a single, fixed $\mathcal{L}$-structure, and the main question we are interested in is the way the elements of that structure interact with each other. When we are working with embeddings, the ambient universe we are working in is the collection of all $\mathcal{L}$-structures, and the main question we are interested in is the way that those $\mathcal{L}$-structures interact with each other. This is a slightly reductionist view of things, but it's at least a useful slogan for understanding why embeddings and valuations are *entirely* different kinds of objects; it's not just that they are defined differently or employ different notations, but that they have completely different *scopes* and *uses*. So, when you write

> I really couldn't come up with a good way of expressing the idea of an $\mathcal{L}$-embedding using this notation,

that is not a bad sign, since these two notions involve different ideas! Instead of trying to relate them to each other, it is best to see them as being two distinct *tools*, which we use in different circumstances depending on what questions we are interested in answering. To use a metaphor, one is like a screwdriver and one is like a hammer; although we could use a screwdriver as a hammer in a pinch, that's not the right way to use it, and it's best to see them as distinct tools with their own distinct uses!

---

**Edit:** Following your edit to your post and your comment below, am I correct that you are asking whether there is a way to express that embeddings commute with term evaluation using the notation for valuations in your post? If so, the answer is yes. Fix an embedding $\pi:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$. Then, for any valuation $u$ on $\mathcal{M}$, we can define the "pushforward" valuation $\pi\circ u$ on $\mathcal{N}$. If $u$ assigns a variable $v_i$ to an element $m_i\in M$, then $\pi\circ u$ assigns $v_i$ to $\pi(m_i)\in N$. Now, using the notation from your second source, given any term $t$, we will have $\pi(u^*_\mathcal{M}(t))=(\pi\circ u)^*_\mathcal{N}(t)$; as an exercise, prove this by induction on the term $t$. In particular, when $u$ maps the free variables of $t$ to the tuple $\bar{a}$, then this equation expresses precisely that $\pi(t^{\mathcal{M}}(\bar{a}))=t^{\mathcal{N}}(\pi(\bar{a}))$, where the latter equation uses the notation of Gabe's notes. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I think the thing I still don't understand is that these conventions for valuations should be on some level interchangeable right? Using the first convention for valuations, there was a proposition that said that $\pi(v_i^\mathcal{M}(a))=v_i^\mathcal{N}(\pi(a))$, for any variable $v_i$. How would I state this proposition, using the second convention for valuations?

Comment: dear @WillHarris, I have added a paragraph to my post to address your comment :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Really appreciate the effort put into the high quality answer :)

Comment: I will try to prove this by induction now

Comment: Atticus Stonestrom, I tried to the induction but got stuck. Would appreciate if you could point out what I'm missing. I posted my attempt as an answer. Again, I very much appreciate your efforts to help me understand.

Comment: dear @WillHarris my pleasure, I am very happy the answer helped! :) you are very nearly there with your induction argument... I will write a comment beneath it to clarify the next step you should take

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Atticus Stonestrom. I'm stuck for doing this induction...
With the old convention it makes sense to me:

Let $t=f(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, and the proposition holds for all $t_i$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi(t^\mathcal{M}(\bar{a}))&=\pi(f^\mathcal{M}(t_1^\mathcal{M}(\bar a),\dots,t_n^\mathcal{M}(\bar a)))\tag{def. of interpretation of functions}\\
&=f^\mathcal{N}(\pi(t_1^\mathcal{M}(\bar a)),\dots,\pi(t_n^\mathcal{M}(\bar a)))\tag{def. of embedding}\\
&=f^\mathcal{N}(t_1^\mathcal{N}(\pi[\bar a]),\dots,t_n^\mathcal{N}(\pi[\bar a]))\tag{by inductive assumption}\\
&=t^\mathcal{N}(\pi[\bar a]).\tag{def. of interpretation of functions}
\end{align*}
$$

So I tried to follow this with the second convention and got stuck:
$$
\pi(w_\mathcal{M}^*(t))=\pi(f^\mathcal{M}(w_\mathcal{M}^*(t_1),\dots,w_\mathcal{M}^*(t_n)))\tag{def. of valuation of functions}
$$
and then I got stuck trying to apply the definition of embedding onto this quantity. Sorry I know these are really really basic questions :/

Comment: you are nearly there! we know that $\pi(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t)))=\pi(f^{\mathcal{M}}(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_1),\dots,w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_n)))$. now, as in your first computation, since $\pi$ is an embedding we know that $\pi(f^{\mathcal{M}}(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_1),\dots,w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_n)))$ equals to $f^\mathcal{N}(\pi(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_1)),\dots,\pi(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_1)))$. furthermore, by the inductive hypothesis, $\pi(w^*_\mathcal{M}(t_i))=(\pi\circ w)^*_\mathcal{N}(t_i)$ for each $i$. so our expression is equal to $f^\mathcal{N}((\pi\circ w)^*_\mathcal{N}(t_1),\dots,(\pi\circ w)^*_\mathcal{N}(t_n))$

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much. I feel satisfied I understand now :D

Comment: wonderful, I am so happy to hear it!! :) (ps, you should absolutely not worry about it being a basic question!!! these are intricate ideas, and it is excellent that you are making sure to understand the basics extremely thoroughly and carefully before moving on! that approach and that level of thoroughness will serve you extremely well as you continue pursuing the field :) )

Comment: Thank you! I will take your advice with me!